# How to make Outlook show the unread count of a folder, including its sub-folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a folder in MS Outlook called **Technology**, and under technology I have **Software** and **Hardware**.

If I setup rules to automatically forward email to **Software** or **Hardware** folder, I don't realize there are any unread mail unless I expand the **Technology** Folder.

I would expect **Technology** itself to show that there are unread items in its folder structure.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's a shame that MS adds tons of features but ignores such an essential feature that basically breaks using subfolders with filters.

Comment: Microsoft, this feature would be super duper handy dandy!

Comment: Well, this question is over 10 Years old. If only Microsoft would do simple market research and/or read the internet for feedback... Maybe before 2030 this will be a feature!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I have a partial answer for you that I use to show counts of unread items in sub folders.

This method gives an overall count of ALL unread items; but not a unread count for each sub folder.

You set this up once, and it will keep track with no further input from you.

I have my Outlook window configured to show set up to show the Navigation pane (**Alt-F1**) like this

[image]

I then create a search folder to count the unread mail, as shown in the next two pictures:

[image]

[image]

This keeps a count of the unread items and will show a list of them. Drag the **Unread Mail** folder to the **Favorites** pane within the **Navigation Pane** so that it is always visible even when the **Search Folders** is collapsed.

[image]

As a bonus, I find this is a very convenient way to keep track of all FLAGGED items,

Comment: Ahh really nice solution :) +1 and +beer!  Even today using Outlook 2010 this still is the only way to do it.

Comment: Outlook 2013, and STILL this feature isn't implemented. YAY priorities.

Comment: This link helped me too https://www.msoutlook.info/question/unread-item-count-collapsed-folders

Comment: It's 2021, and STILL this feature isn't implemented. YAY priorities.

Answer (score 10):

The only easy way to make Outlook show the Unread count of the Software or Hardware sub-folders, is to move them to the same level as Inbox, Outbox, and all the other Outlook-supplied folders.

In effect, abolishing the hierarchy is the only solution. The unread count doesn't propagate, and has never done so in any version of Outlook, past or present. Nor does any addon exist that can do so (some such addons may at the most show you alerts for unread mail).

This solution isn't as shocking as it seems, since the only other solution : creating custom search folders, is essentially the same thing. Except that it aggregates all search folders without hierarchy under the "Search Folders" folder, instead of under the root folder.

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a "Custom Search Folder", similar to what was described above, that looks at each subfolder you want to watch.

Start by creating a Search Folder. Then select the last option , "Create a custom search folder". Name it and click the Criteria button. In the "More Choices" tab, select the checkbox for "Only items that are" and select "unread" in the droplist.  Then in the advanced tab, create the custom criteria. This can be teadeous if you have a lot of folders, but it will work. For the "Field" use "In Folder". Set the condition to "IS" and set the Value be the name of the subfolder.  If you add a rule for each subfolder you will get a total unread for all subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

How about instead of using folders, use categories. By all means have one level of folders, but under that the categories will work in the same way (except you wont get that hierarchical treeview on the left). As a bonus, you can assign more than one category to a mail item. Tag and search works better than the traditional filing cabinet approach anyway.

Comment: where can you see categories listed?

Comment: when you go into any folder, you can set it up to order by category, then collapse all

Comment: also, right click on a column header in the inbox grid, click on Field Chooser. you can select category from that list

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a Primary Folder named "Accounting Department" then you have subfolders inside with different employees from the Accounting department. For example:

```
Accounting Department
      Mary
      Joe
      Alex
```

For Mary, Joe, & Alex you have already set up the rule that if you receive an email from Mary put it in the Mary folder and so on.

The way you get the collapsed folder to show all unread emails amongst your subfolders is by creating a new rule that states: when an email is from Mary; or Joe; or Alex; then put a **COPY** of the email into folder: Accounting Department.

Thus every time one of your subfolders receive an email a copy gets sent to the primary folder which will keep tally of how many emails. FYI, this is only been tested by me in 2007, but I'm sure it works in the newer ones also.

Comment: But doesn't this leave the unread copy in the superfolder even after you've read it (and perhaps deleted it) from the subfolder?

Answer (score -3):

1. In Outlook - Go to File | Account Settings, then "Account Settings in the drop down".
2. Select the "Data Files" tab.
3. Select your account/location in the displayed list and click the "Settings..." tool button.
4. In the displayed dialog select the "Advanced" tab.
5. Uncheck "Use Cached Exchange Mode".
6. Click "OK".

If you close and reopen Outlook now it may work, if it doesn't continue reading:

7. Close Outlook.
8. Start Outlook using "/cleanips". I have 32-bit Outlook so this is where it was on my system.

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE"/cleanips
9. After Outlook starts. Use the above instructions to go turn "Use Cached Exchange Mode" back on again and quit Outlook. Then start Outlook again with "/cleanips".

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE"/cleanips

After doing this, the unread email counts for each Exchange folder should display again.

Comment: As I see that people only downvoted this, but never explained why. The simple reason here is that you are addressing the wrong issue. It is about subfolders not counting for the total of unread items, not about the count not showing at all. This is a known issue in Outlook, with a few workarounds, but doesn't have an actual sollution yet.