# How to make Outlook 2010 show unread count of folder, including its sub-folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

2 years ago [leora has asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/67433/how-to-make-outlook-show-unread-count-of-folder-including-its-sub-folders) and there is no answer for Outlook 2003 & 2007.
Does anyone know how to do it in Outlook 2010 or just "Could a newer and better mail client do this **simple** thing"?

---

In fact, there is a tip to do this thing, but quite dummy and personally, I hate to do these things **manually for any mail box I have**.
Right-click on `Search Folders` - `New Search Folder...` - `Unread Mail` - `OK`
Right-click on **new** `Unread Mail` (may be Unread1 if there is another Unread box) -- `Customize this Search Folder` - `Browse...` -- choose the folder you want to show unread count and don't forget the check box *Search sub folder*.
Right-click and choose *Show in Favorites* to get focus.

Comment: @greg84
in next 2 days if there aren't any answers, I'll answer as above.

Comment: Do you really need to show this count in realtime? Maybe the one-click report on all your mailboxes and folders (with message counts) will help?