# Unread message count including subfolders in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Copy of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/67433/how-to-make-outlook-show-the-unread-count-of-a-folder-including-its-sub-folders). Maybe something changed in 2013.

If I have a folder in MS Outlook 2013 called **Parent** and under **Parent** I have **A** and **B**.

If I setup rules to automatically forward email to **A** or **B** folder, I don't realize they is any unread mail unless I expand the **Parent** Folder.

I would expect **Parent** itself to show that there are unread items in its folder structure.

Is there a way to do this (besides search folders)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

There's no change in Outlook 2013 for this feature. As you said, (and the old question) you can create search folder to check the same.

To create a new Search Folder use

Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007 
File -> New Search Folder
Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013
Folder tab -> New Search Folder